# PINE SCRIPT 5: Drawing lines based on session input data

Tags: session, line, tradingview-api

I'm trying to draw a simple line at a price level from the open and close of a session input in a TradingView indicator.

So for example draw a price line at a defined price level from 1800-2100 chart time.

I've done this using unix time but this is really clunky and awkward to work with, especially considering I'm already doing other things within the indicator using already established session input data. Would be cool to draw the levels with this data as well instead of having their own (janky) code.

Right now I'm manipulating the session data with str and math functions, then creating unix times from it. And this is not going very well.

I've been searching over a week on this and not much out there, here's hoping!

Comment: maybe this can help you: https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-track-highslows-for-a-specific-timeframe

Comment: That helped Thank you! Wish I could make it a dotted line rather than circles, but I won't be too picky since everything else works exactly as I was hoping for. Thanks again.